# Save and Send to Sharepoint error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, word

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010 and a sharepoint 2010 site.

And I'm having troubles with **file locations** when saving files back to sharepoint library.

First, when I open a file from sharepoint site, edit and try to save, the default location is not the location of the library the file was at.

If I try to do *'File>Save and Send> Save to Sharepoint'* and select a **recent location**, or if I click on **find location**, I get the following error message:

> Could not Find `http://xxxxx.xxx/DocumentLibraryA/FolderA`

The only way I'm able to save is via *'File>Save as'* and input the **url** on the **file name** field.

This issue is not happening with every computer I try to open files from sharepoint. On some other computers, I am able to open the file from the library and it comes with the default location, and if I do *'File>Save and Send> Save to Sharepoint'*, it opens normaly.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure if this fixes. Open Internet Explorer and add the site in Trusted sites.

Comment: Actually, I tought it worked, but it seems that only worked for the computers that were only not getting the default file location. I still have some users that gets the error when trying to 'save and send'... unfortunatly